# Split Table After X Number of Rows & Add Text in While Loop (Using TCPDF)

Tags: mysql, sql, tcpdf

I have this statement which produces as many rows as it should do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID ORDER BY     PRICE * QUANTITY DESC");

$total=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];
$description = $row['NAME'];
$unitprice = $row['PRICE'];
$lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY'];
$total=$total+$lineprice;

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

$tbl .= '
<tr>
    <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($quantity,0).'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($unitprice,2).'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;" align="right" ><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($lineprice,2).'</p></td>
</tr>
';

 $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```

As mentioned this returns the correct data.  However, I have a footer on the page set with SETXY within TCPDF and the table goes over this.  What I need is to add the text:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
```

After 10 rows and then the table continues on the next page.

Any ideas?  If this can't be done, is there anyway of setting the setxy to not just sit in the background of the page?

Comment: Why did you take out the relevant code section and put `// foreach item in your array...`?

Comment: Your loop is wrong. You're creating $tbl_header and $tbl_footer again and again, and the loop should end before you `$pdf->writeHTML`

Comment: It's not incorrect.  It prints out here: $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

Comment: Did you really mean to start and end your table between each row? That is what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple looping counter:

```
$tbl = '';
$counter = 0;

// foreach item in your array...
$counter++;
if ($counter > 9) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $counter = 0;
}
$tbl .= '
```

Edit: you probably want to refactor the way you're looping but as you have it written now the solution is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID ORDER BY     PRICE * QUANTITY DESC");

$total=0;
$counter = 0;  //implement a counter
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$counter++; //increment the counter on each loop

$quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];
$description = $row['NAME'];
$unitprice = $row['PRICE'];
$lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY'];
$total=$total+$lineprice;

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

$tbl .= '
<tr>
    <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($quantity,0).'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($unitprice,2).'</p></td>
    <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;" align="right" ><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($lineprice,2).'</p></td>
</tr>
';

if ($counter > 9) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $counter = 0;
}

 $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, just need to get my head around it a little.  Unfortunately this doesn't split the tables after 9 rows on to a new page.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Just had to add the footer above the addPage so it appeared on both pages but it's worked a treat.  Thank you very much for your help.  Much appreciated. Andy

Comment: hello, I know this is very old post. But I have same problem. When I am using your code nothing is displaying.

Comment: @Abdullah please create a new question with your code snippet, desired outcome, and error messages.