# How to Split Database Table into Pages in TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf, fpdf

I am making a small PDF generation tool for my client. I am using TCPDF because the we need arabic font to be used in it. I am getting result from database. Now client requirement is 20 result per page. I searched alot on internet. But there is nothing much I found. Here is my code please have a look.

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 18);
$pdf->Ln(40);
$content = '';

$content .='
<table>
';

$counter=0;
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM record");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $counter++;

    $name = $row['rname'];
        $country = $row['rcountry'];
        $uid = $row['ruid'];

        $content .='

        <tr>
            <td>'.$name.'</td>
            <td>'.$country.'</td>
            <td>'.$uid.'</td>
        </tr>';
}

$content .='</table>';

$pdf->WriteHTML($content, true, 0, true, 0);
```

I tried following solution also but its not showing any result 
[Split Table After X Number of Rows & Add Text in While Loop (Using TCPDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164219/split-table-after-x-number-of-rows-add-text-in-while-loop-using-tcpdf/21164376#21164376)

Comment: Simply use your $counter variable to close the table and re-open it when you get to 20 rows. You may have to pad using <br /> between tables to get the pagination right. A better solution would be to directly write to the PDF instead of using HTML.

Comment: Hi. Actually i have Arabic words in my data. I can only use Arabic data using HTML